# Performance of python's control flow statements

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I'm reading the Python wiki about [loops](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Loops) and it says

> List comprehensions were added to Python in version 2.0 as well. They provide a syntactically more compact and more efficient way of writing the above for loop:

However, I have found that when I tested this, I'm getting some unexpected results.

```
In [22]: def while_loop(n):
    ...:     i = 0
    ...:     while i < n:
    ...:         i+=1
    ...:

In [23]: def while_loop_2(n):
    ...:     while n > 0:
    ...:         n-=1
    ...:

In [24]: def for_loop(n):
    ...:     for _ in range(n):
    ...:         pass
    ...:

In [30]: %timeit(for_loop(1000000))
10 loops, best of 3: 23.9 ms per loop

In [31]: %timeit(while_loop(1000000))
10 loops, best of 3: 37.1 ms per loop

In [32]: %timeit(while_loop_2(1000000))
10 loops, best of 3: 38 ms per loop

In [33]: %timeit([1 for _ in range(1000000)])
10 loops, best of 3: 43.2 ms per loop
```

Which leads me to some questions:

1. Why is the `for` loop so much faster than the list comprehension? (It appears to be nearly twice as fast)
2. Why is `while_loop_2` slower than `while_loop`? Why does the difference of incrementing vs decrementing the counter yield the difference in speed? My naivety leads me to believe less lines of code = faster - clearly this isn't the case

**EDIT:**
This was done in Python 2.7. In 3.6 `while_loop_2` is actually faster than `while_loop`. So new question:

3. What is the difference in the `while` loops between Python 2.7 and 3.x?

Comment: reason for #1, your list comprehension also creates a new list (which comes with cost) and hence it's comparision with plain for loop is not efficient way to judge performance of list comprehension. Instead you should be comparing your list comprehension with other modes of creating list

Comment: Your `for_loop() : pass` is not a fair comparison with the two while loops which perform augmented assignment.

Comment: Compare the list comp with a `for i in range...: alist.append(i)` loop. A list comp returns a list of some sort, it doesn't just iterate or count.  But for similar tasks the speed differences are modest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a preamble, you should be aware that your "comparisons" should be analysed in isolation (and not compared against each other), because

1. The for loop is a fixed iterator doing nothing inside its body
2. The while loops perform decrement/increment in their body, and
3. The list comprehension is more than just a `for` loop, and with that said, I segue into answering question #1.

---

#1, Because the `for` loop iterates. The list comprehension iterates, *and* creates a list in memory. This, of course, contributes to the total time taken. This alone should be enough to convince you, but if it isn't, take a look at the disassembled byte code to see what each is doing. You can use the `dis` module to do so. I actually use `dis` to answer your third question.

---

#2, As for this, I can't reproduce on python3.6.

```
%%timeit
i = 0; n = 100000
while i < n: i += 1

11.5 ms ± 65.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

```
%%timeit
n = 100000
while  n > 0: n -= 1

10.8 ms ± 380 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

In general, the decrement based loop should be a tad faster because comparisons against 0 (`n > 0`) usually are faster than comparisons against non-zero values (`i < n`). But the delta is usually "seriously, don't worry about it" kinda small.

---

To answer #3, we'll need to dig a bit. Let's look at the bytecode.

```
import dis
```

python3.6

> ```
> dis.dis(
> '''n = 100000
> while  n > 0: n -= 1'''
> )
>
>   1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (100000)
>               2 STORE_NAME               0 (n)
>
>   2           4 SETUP_LOOP              20 (to 26)
>         >>    6 LOAD_NAME                0 (n)
>               8 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
>              10 COMPARE_OP               4 (>)
>              12 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       24
>              14 LOAD_NAME                0 (n)
>              16 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
>              18 INPLACE_SUBTRACT
>              20 STORE_NAME               0 (n)
>              22 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            6
>         >>   24 POP_BLOCK
>         >>   26 LOAD_CONST               3 (None)
>              28 RETURN_VALUE
> ```

python2.7

> ```
> dis.dis(
> '''n = 100000
> while  n > 0: n -= 1'''
> )
>           0 JUMP_FORWARD    15648 (to 15651)
>           3 SLICE+2        
>           4 <49>           
>           5 <48>           
>           6 <48>           
>           7 <48>           
>           8 <48>           
>           9 <48>           
>          10 UNARY_POSITIVE 
>          11 CONTINUE_LOOP   26984
>          14 IMPORT_NAME      8293 (8293)
>          17 SLICE+2        
>          18 JUMP_FORWARD    15904 (to 15925)
>          21 SLICE+2        
>          22 <48>           
>          23 INPLACE_DIVIDE 
>          24 SLICE+2        
>          25 JUMP_FORWARD    11552 (to 11580)
>          28 DELETE_SUBSCR  
>          29 SLICE+2        
>          30 <49>
> ```

Note that there are huge differences in the generated bytecode. The difference lies here.

Comment: @aydow for #3, I can only speculate as I am not a core dev, but a LOT of changes between 2 and 3 were mostly performance related... and the while could be one among them for all I know.

Comment: @aydow The biggest difference I assume would have to be with how the bytecode is generated. Using `dis`, you can take a look.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to test the `above loop` in the link:

```
newlist = []
for word in oldlist:
    newlist.append(word.upper())
```

---

iteration with list append:

```
In [104]: %%timeit
     ...: alist = []
     ...: for i in range(10000):
     ...:    alist.append(i)
     ...: 
1.07 ms ± 10.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

equivalent list comprehension

```
In [105]: timeit [i for i in range(10000)]
491 µs ± 20.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

This is indeed faster than the list append loop.

creating the same list from a range object:

```
In [106]: timeit list(range(10000))
265 µs ± 679 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Do nothing iteration:

```
In [107]: %%timeit
     ...: for i in range(10000):
     ...:    pass
     ...: 
273 µs ± 9.15 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Some other list creations:

```
In [109]: timeit list(map(lambda i:i, range(10000)))
1.41 ms ± 3.12 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
In [110]: timeit list(i for i in range(10000))
784 µs ± 19.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```